# httpd.conf variables : What is the difference between ${var} and %{var}?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

What is the difference between `${var}` and `%{var}` in httpd.conf?

How and when would one use `${}` and `%{}`?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html mentions :

> The values of variables defined with the Define of or shell
>   environment variables can be used in configuration file lines using
>   the syntax ${VAR}.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html mentions:

> Server-Variables:These are variables of the form %{ NAME_OF_VARIABLE }

and

> RewriteMap expansions:These are expansions of the form ${mapname:key|default}.

Will `${VAR}` be used everywhere in httpd.conf, except in mod_rewrite directive's (like RewriteCond, RewriteRule but except for RewriteMap expansions which use `${}` as in **RewriteRule ^/ex/(.*) ${examplemap:$1}** )

Would a variable set in httpd.conf using `SetEnvIf` Directive, for use in same httpd.conf, be used as `${var}` except when the variable is used with mod_rewrite directive's, where the variable would be used as `%{var}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between ${var} and %{var} in httpd.conf?

Pretty much everything.  There's no hard-and-fast rule that says "`$` does x, `%` does y", because they do different things depending on where and how they're used.

> Will ${VAR} be used everywhere in httpd.conf, except in mod_rewrite directive's

No - `${VAR}` is applied as a replacement in *every* location throughout the config, even in a mod_rewrite related line.  These can only be defined at startup using the `-D` option passed to the httpd binary, or the `Define` directive.

This can be done because those variables must not contain a `:` character, whereas the `RewriteMap` usage must contain a `:` character.  This allows for the `$` to be used in extremely different ways with no conflict - the parser sees the `:` and knows that it's not supposed to be replacing that.

> Would a variable set in httpd.conf using SetEnvIf Directive, for use in same httpd.conf, be used as ${var} except when the variable is used with mod_rewrite directive's, where the variable would be used as %{var}?

No.  Environment variables are not the same as variables set via `-D` or `Define` - they're a completely separate per-request context (those are the ones you're setting with `SetEnvIf`), that only certain directives will use.  They're specifically mentioned where supported - in mod_rewrite they're `%{ENV:variable}`, in logs they're `%{variable}e`, and a lot of directives have a logic check that looks like `env=variable`.

---

So, basically; it's a confusing mess - a testament to the web server's history over the past couple decades.  Probably the main thing that's confusing you is that mod_rewrite's syntax doesn't extend to any other part of the config in any way; it's all different.  The main point to take from all this is that there isn't a governing 'rule' to make all of this make sense - a `$` in one spot means something completely different from a `$` in another spot.

A few handy reference points:

1. If you're looking to set a variable statically when Apache starts, use `Define` and `${VAR}` to replace once, on Apache's startup.  This is mostly useful for when you want to do something like share config files between a development and production environment - but it's not to be confused with the use of the `$` from `RewriteMap`, which always contains a `:`.
2. If you're looking to work with variables in specific requests, then environment variables are what you're after - but you cannot make assumptions about the syntax that you'll use to get at them when used with a specific directive.  You'll need to check the documentation for that directive.
3. When mod_rewrite is in question, throw out everything you thought you knew about variables and their syntax.  It has its own set of variables in `%{VAR}`, you can get at your 'normal' environment variables with `%{ENV:VAR}`, and you can set environment variables with `[E=VAR]`.

Comment: wow! thanks for such a lengthy write up! It will take me a while to digest this. Quite strange that Apache docs don't document this in one place, this must be quite confusing to lot of newbies.

Comment: Yeah - their docs aren't bad for specific concepts, but the 'big picture' stuff like this is much less clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at source code of mod_rewrite, and found that notes in comments (do_expand function):

```
        /* variable lookup */
        else if (*p == '%') {
        ...
        /* map lookup */
        else {     /* *p == '$' */
```

so it looks, like % are for exact variables, while $ are for lookups in hash tables ("maps").
also, all mod_rewrite expansions are completely independed from core -- whole expansion done in module by itself.

I was thought earlier, but that was wrong:

> ${} vars are uses environment of project, and evaluated at time of
>   config parse.
>
> %{} vars are uses environment of request, and evaluated at time
>   request parsed. mod_rewrite uses %{} symantic to prevent config-time
>   interpolation made by httpd core.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please include the link to original documentation for this and if possible, link to a tutorial?

Comment: I have never seen that in clear text in documentation. That is how i have understand why that was done. And that was wrong :)